# Do I need to prepare and bind a $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

My question is simple, I have this session user:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

and I want to do a select with it:

```
select * from online where user='$user' order by id desc LIMIT 1
```

Do I need to prepare a $_SESSION variable as I do with POST and GET? If I do not, is there a chance of SQL injection?

```
select * from online where user=? order by id desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Use prepared statements and you don't even have to ask such things yourself!

Comment: POST, GET, SESSION are variables on server. All of them have chance for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Do I need to prepare a $_SESSION variable as I do with POST and GET?**

Yes you do. It's as unsafe as a normal bald `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

**2. If I do not, is there a chance of sql injection?**

There is such a thing as [Session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) which makes (almost) everything possible with sessions. You definitely need to look into that. As I said before a Session is as unsafe as a `$_POST` and `$_GET`. So yes you have a chance of SQL injection.